# How to properly escape special characters, when setting in element attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes

I am getting the values from backend and making a group of checkboxes, one of the value not setting properly with my check box..

the test reads like this: "French (Cote d'Ivoire)"

But in the output i am getting result like this:

```
<label><input value="French (Cote d" ivoire)'="" type="checkbox">French (Cote d'Ivoire)</label>
```

I understand that, the "'" - have to scape. for that i did a replace work, but still the issue not fixed,

here is my try:

```
$.map(data["allLocales"], function(value, i){

                var name = value.name;
                    name.replace("'", "&quot;") even i tried name.replace("'", "\'") - no luck

                if(i % 5 === 0 ){
                    col0 += "<label><input value='"+ name +"' type='checkbox' />"+name+"</label>"
                }else if(i % 5 === 1){
                    col1 += "<label><input value='"+ name +"' type='checkbox' />"+name+"</label>"
                }else if(i % 5 === 2){
                    col2 += "<label><input value='"+ name +"' type='checkbox' />"+name+"</label>"
                }else if(i % 5 === 3){
                    col3 += "<label><input value='"+ name +"' type='checkbox' />"+name+"</label>"
                }else if(i % 5 === 4){
                    col4 += "<label><input value='"+ name +"' type='checkbox' />"+name+"</label>"
                }

            })
```

how to escape the "'" - single cote properly, and in case of any other special characters like

```
$, &,%
```

if i get in future how to handle that scenarios..?

Comment: As an aside: If you'd make `col0...4` properties of an object rather than local variables, you'd be able to access them programmatically, `var cols = { col0: '', col1: '', ... }; cols['col' + i%5]` and you could remove that big condition and just treat everything in one call.

Comment: Or if they're global variables, you could acheive the same with `window['col'+ i%5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(element).attr(attrName, value)` to modify attribute, and `$(element).text(value)` for text content.

Do not manipulate/concatenate HTML yourself as bad code will easily lead to security issues.

Comment: In this scenario, i am grouping the elements.. how to handle this? can you show me a demo.. or sample pls?

Comment: when i group like this: col0 += $("<label />").text(name); i am getting a result as 'object' - in html

Comment: Your code doesn't seems complete, so I will demo the concept:

`col0 = $('<label />').text(name).prepend($('<input type="checkbox" />').val(name));`